# BCP queryout - Large data

Tags: sql, sqlbulkcopy, bcp

- SQL Server 2008
- Using the command prompt

I'm trying to write a table to text format using bcp. The table is roughly 13 million rows. The columns, 5 of them, consist of an int, 2 nvarchar(max) and 2 varchar(max).

When I attempt to use the following bcp command:

```
bcp "SELECT * from table" QueryOut "C:\file.txt" -U user -P password -S "server\server" -c -C RAW -a 65535
```

The performance is dreadful to say the least. It can take roughly 1 hour to process all rows. When I limit the query to just the one int column, it takes about 50 seconds. The int column and 1 varchar(max) takes about 3 minutes.

So it's obvious to me that the issue appears to be either the declaration of the column OR the data in the column. So of the data in one of the varchar(max) columns can be about 7.5 million in length (it's rare, but happens).

I've tried using a view and I've tried inserting records into a physical temp table. Nothing has helped the performance. I'm currently trying to insert into a view if the length is less than 1 million.

Is this a limitation of BCP? I know the amount of pages for some of those columns will be very large, but I cannot find anything online or in the API/Description about such limitations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have not used the nvarchar(max) to the fullest length that is more than 4000 then covert them from nvarchar(max) to nvarchar(4000), the same goes for varchar(max) as well. Once that is done give bcp a try.

Comment: You have narrowed down to issue already quite a bit. Well done. Narrow it further by excluding rows that have a lot of variable length data. Just add a WHERE clause to remove them. See if the times improve drastically although only a few rows have been excluded.

Comment: I believe your search for a SQL Server performance problem is likely to be a dead end. Reading 13 million rows is not going to take one hour except under very contrived circumstances.

Comment: I've tried removing the rows with the large data with query (conditional with), but does the query still do a scan of that table regardless? The performance, I might have screwed up honestly, isn't significantly different

Comment: For anyone that cares, I figured out that if I run my query with limitations on the size (less than 2 mil in length only) INTO a physical table and then bcp, it's much, much faster. The issue is clearly size - but again, no idea why.

Comment: OK, this now more looks like a SQL Server issue. Rebuild all indexes on that table. REORGANIZE with LOB_COMPACTION = ON. Does that help? How big is the table and how much memory does the server have?

Comment: About 73 GB, server memory isn't an issue at all.

Comment: Going to attempt a straight dump from the table in question to a copy of it, no other modifications. Then I'll test that table. You might be right usr.

Comment: Removed those rows and it processed all rows in 49 seconds. A solution, but not an answer unfortunately. I may at some point really investigate the "threshold" for performance in bcp. 2 million was arbitrary based on our data, but I want to learn more.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for all the updates along. However, did you find the answer to this? I'm trying to explore good practice for bcp to dump large amount of data (10m+ rows) from MSSQL server.